# How to feed multi-channel spectrograms to Deep Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, conv-neural-network, hidden-markov-model

I am using a 14 channel EEG device. To do away with the need for any handcrafted features, I wish to implement an ML classification task with the EEG data collected using deep neural networks (such as 2D-CNN) directly on the spectrograms.

I get decent results by concatenating all 14 spectrograms (per training example) side by side, to get a single spectrogram. Though this is the only thing that makes sense to me, what is the normal/right way to feed multi-channel spectrograms to a deep neural network?

Comment: And if you use 3D convolutions, for this you have to stack each spectogram "behind" each other. Creating a 3D tensor, including your batchsize you will have 4D tensor